# ES6 imports causing side effects from uncalled functions in Typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm currently attempting to write unit tests for an application, and have split my code into functionality that can and cannot easily unit tested, like below:

```js
// util.ts
import { thing } from "./side_effect.js";

// this function is used elsewhere
export function reliesOnThing() {
  // This function needs stateful information generated at runtime that
  // cannot be easily unit tested
  thing();
}

export function statelessFunction() {
  // this function doesn't rely on any side effects or runtime deps
  console.log("foo");
}
```

I was hoping to be able to import and test `statelessFunction()` from another file.

```js
// test.ts
import { statelessFunction } from "util.js";

// i need to access `statelessFunction()`, but don't need `reliesOnThing()`
// do some stuff blah blah
statelessFunction();
```

However, when I use `statelessFunction()`, the `thing` import from `./side_effect.js` is evaluated,
which causes a bunch of unwanted side effects when running `test.ts`.

The call to `statelessFunction()` causes `thing` to be evaluated, which causes another `thing` to be evaluated, and so on.

I could possibly split everything into separate files based on whether or not they need access to `thing`, but that seems inefficient and not a scalable solution.

Is there any way to access the import `statelessFunction`, without triggering a chain of side effects caused by imports that *don't affect* `statelessFunction()`.

Comment: Importing a module runs the code of the module, and there's nothing you can do to prevent that other than break up your code differently.

Comment: You need to make './side_effect.js' not have anything running when imported. The normal way to do it is to export some sort of `init()` function. But if you call `side_effect.init()` at the top level anyway you're back to the same problem. You'd then need `util.ts` to export its own `init()` to avoid side_effect's `init()` from being called unintentionally. There is a solution. Make `thing()` self initialize. That is, put whatever code you need to run in `side_effect.js` in `thing()` instead of at the top level and run that code only once using a variable as a flag